# Convert json array of primitve types using gson

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2 and I've a method which response is an array of numbers

```
[2,4,9,12, ... ]
```

What type do I have to enclose in Call< > in order to parse the response?

Comment: you can use ResponseBody, if you dont have a defined model